# Find the solution of $x^2-4=[x]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

I am able to find the solution by using the help of graph. I know $x^2-4$ will cut $[x]$ only at $-2$ and $2$ and then I am able to find the answer.

I want to know, can we approach this question in any other way like replacing $x$ by $[x]$ and $\{x\}$, where $\{ \ \ \}$ is fractional part of $x$.

Then we can make relation in $[x]$ and $\{x\}$ and don't need to plot the graph roughly.

Comment: Can you please define [x]?

Comment: Why don't you do that ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust let ME TRY but please return to this question if i am unable to do it in 15 minutes

Comment: Let me drop it if I can't solve in five minutes.

Comment: @AshishKumar what is the definition of [x]?

Comment: [x] is the floor function

Comment: [x] is actually the closest integer to x, aka just rounding to the nearest integer, not the floor function

Comment: @FruDe we are taught [x] is greatest integer function [x],<=x and it should be integer

Comment: I see, that is usually identified as $\lceil x \rceil$. Make sure to define it in the problem because there are differing terminologies @AshishKumar

Answer (score 1):

*HINT*

$x^2 = [x] + 4 \in \mathbb{N}$

Then:

$x^2 = [x] + 4 \ge x + 3 \Rightarrow x \ge [\ldots, +\infty)$

Also:

$x^2 = [x] + 4 \le x + 4 \Rightarrow x \in [\ldots, \ldots]$

Then you just need to consider $x$ from intersection.

Comment: Why is it downvoted?

Comment: i have not  downvoted let me read

Comment: @AshishKumar I don't think you could downvote even if you wanted too.

Comment: @openspace there are only two solutions

Comment: the solutions are root7 and -root3

Comment: @AshishKumar For those solutions, it looks as though you meant the ceiling, not the floor.

Answer (score 1):

(In this post, I'm assuming we're really talking about the *floor* of $x$, that is, the greatest integer *at most* $x$ — which I'm writing as $\lfloor x\rfloor$.)

One way we could solve this algebraically is to notice the floor of $x$ is bounded:

$$x-1\lt\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$$

So if we have $x^2-4=\lfloor x\rfloor$, then $x-1\lt x^2-4\le x$.

Solving the left inequality, we get the solution set:

$$A=\left(-\infty,\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)\cup\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2},\infty\right)$$

Solving the right inequality, we get:

$$B=\left[\frac{1-\sqrt{15}}{2},\frac{1+\sqrt{15}}{2}\right]$$

Since these inequalities must be true simultaneously, the solutions are contained in the set:

$$A\cap B=\left[\frac{1-\sqrt{15}}{2},\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)\cup\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2},\frac{1+\sqrt{15}}{2}\right]$$

From here, we can notice that the floor of the left region is $-2$ and the floor of the right region is $2$ (since $3<\sqrt{13}<\sqrt{15}<4$). Finding the solution to $x^2-4=-2$ that is in the left region gives us $x=-\sqrt2$; finding the solution to $x^2-4=2$ in the right region is $x=\sqrt6$.